# Why doesn't Activity invoke onPause() after my FragmentDialog dismiss?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

On my Activity, there is a button, click it and show a FragmentDialog that display a EditText for user's input, and after user's input, I want to refresh activity's view, I want to do that In `onResume()`, but, I found

```
MyFragmentDialog mfd = new MyFragmentDialog();
mfd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

didn't call the `onPause()` and when dialog dismiss, `onResume()` won't be called.

So, how could I solve this problem and understand what happened?